# Looking up a value in a nested dictionary to get a value in a separate dictionary but same parent dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

In the response that comes back from an API request. I get a format that is a list of nested dictionaries. for example.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 1
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "Conversion"
      },
      "7": {
        "value": "HVAC"
      }
    },
```

I can easily get past the the first dictionary using r['data']. At this point, each list item is a record in a database. r['data'][0] gives me a dictionary of what the field ('3') is and then a dictionary of what the value is ({'value': 'Conversion'}).

I want to be able to look up a value like 'Conversion' and have it tell me what the value is for field '3'. Anyway to do this using python?

Comment: It's not super clear what you want. If you were to write a function for this what would be the input arguments and what would be the desired output?

Comment: You code is faulty. Even after fixing it **Can't understand what do you want**

Comment: @NathanAllan Can you guarantee that if there's a dictionary with a value of 'Conversion' that there will be a key of '3'? Is the value of 'Conversion' (if it exists) always going to be associated with key '6'?

Comment: I have a separate dataset with values that match what is found in key '6' like 'Conversion'. I would need it to loop through each of those values and then pull the value from key '3' in this dataset.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Yes, that is guaranteed throughout the rest of the response. and yes the value in key '6' though it may change from 'Conversion' to something else is always associated with key '6'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description doesn't quite fit with reality. Let's have a complete structure:

```
r = {
    "data": [
        {
            "3": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "6": {
                "value": "Conversion"
            },
            "7": {
                "value": "HVAC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*r* is a dictionary. It contains a single key ('data') whose associated value is a list which, in this example, contains one dictionary. That dictionary has 3 keys - "3", "6" and "7". Each of those keys has a value which itself is a dictionary comprised of a single key ('value') and, obviously, an associated value.

You can assert as follows:

```
assert r['data'][0]['6']['value'] == 'Conversion'
```

Hopefully that shows how you can access the lower level value(s)

What's unclear from your question is why would you be searching for 'Conversion' when you want the value from key '3' which would be:

```
r['data'][0]['3']['value']
```

**EDIT:**

```
def get_value(r, from_key, ref_key, value):
    for d in r['data']:
        if d.get(from_key, {}).get('value') == value:
            return d.get(ref_key, {}).get('value')

print(get_value(r, '6', '3', 'Conversion'))
```

Doing it this way offers the flexibility of specifying the relevant keys and value

Comment: I have a separate dataset, that doesn't contain the value from key '3' only the data from key '6'. I need the data from key '3' though for the next steps of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make an assumption that what you are *trying* to say is that you want the index based on the value.

```
r = {...} # your data
def lookup(val, r_data):
  for i in range(len(r_data['data'])): #loops through list based on index
    for k, v in r_data['data'][i].items(): #loops dict with key/value
      if v['value'] == val: #checks if value matches needle
        return "[{}][{}]".format(i, k)
```

This returns '[0][6]'.  I don't know if your data is supposed to be formatted that way... a list within 'data' and then only one dict inside.  But, given this format, this will give you the index.